# React Hooks, trying to replace parts of an object with updated values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-setting-new-state-s6f4x?file=/src/App.js)

New to React and I'm having just a bit of trouble setting a new state with just some fields changed. Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Columns = () => {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBoard({
      columnIds: ["col_id_1", "col_id_2"],
      boardColor: "#2e359e",
      boardDiff: "#FFFFFF",
      boardValue: "Sales"
    });
  }, []);

  const onClick = () => {
    const newBoard = {
      boardColor: "#336699",
      boardDiff: "#CCCCCC",
      boardValue: "Leads"
    };
    setBoard({ ...board, newBoard });
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Change State</button>
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(board, 0, 3)}</pre>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Columns;
```

When I click the button, I get an unexpected state change. Where I just want to replace some values in the object, I get this instead:

```
{
   "columnIds": [
      "col_id_1",
      "col_id_2"
   ],
   "boardColor": "#2e359e",
   "boardDiff": "#FFFFFF",
   "boardValue": "Sales",
   "newBoard": {
      "boardColor": "#336699",
      "boardDiff": "#CCCCCC",
      "boardValue": "Leads"
   }
}
```

I know there is something basic I'm overlooking, but appreciate anyone's help! My sandbox is included in the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

First, you're missing a spread operator. Try:

```
setBoard({...board, ...newBoard})
```

Second, when doing a partial update in a react state setter, it's preferable to use the function version, to ensure that you're always updating the latest possible board (as opposed to the stale one in your closure):

```
setBoard(board => ({...board, ...newBoard}))
```

Finally, when making a callback like onClick, it's preferable to use the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to create it. This ensures that the callbacks object identity is preserved between renders, which reduces unnecessary rerenders:

```
const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    const newBoard = {...};
    setBoard(board => ({...board, ...newBoard}));
}, [setBoard]);
```